# Delete index document using solr java api

Tags: java, solr, lotus-domino, solrj

So here i am using `solr` for indexing document.

now here is my small part code:

```
        db = cmd.start();
        new NotesSolrWriter(db, null);
        SolrHelper slrHelp = new SolrHelper();
        QueryResponse res = slrHelp.queryResults("dontKnow1 ", null);
        SolrDocumentList ids = res.getResults();

        count = ids.size();
        System.out.println(count);
        boolean getServer = getServer();
        if (getServer) {
            for (SolrDocument id : ids) {
                System.out.println("See my id " + id.toString());
                FTIserver.deleteById(id.toString());
                FTIserver.commit();
                // FTIserver.commit(true, true);
            }
        }

        QueryResponse res1 = slrHelp.queryResults("dontKnow1 ", null);
        SolrDocumentList ids1 = res1.getResults();
        int count1 = ids1.size();
        System.out.println("before delete::" + count);
        System.out.println("after delete::" + count1);
```

**output:**

```
See my id SolrDocument[{contid=3BAC9EE84691380265257EEB002BAA77, cmrights=[dummy, dummy1, dummy2], dbtype=MAIL, subject=NotesSlrWriter123, sendto=receiver@gmial123.com, frommail=sender@gmail123.com, posteddate=Tue Oct 27 13:26:57 IST 2015}]
See my id SolrDocument[{contid=F92F9D8BBD65F36365257EEB0040DEFE, cmrights=[dummy, dummy1, dummy2], dbtype=MAIL, subject=NotesSlrWriter123, sendto=receiver@gmial123.com, frommail=sender@gmail123.com, posteddate=Tue Oct 27 17:18:33 IST 2015}]
before delete::2
after delete::2
```

so here what i am trying to do is getting database then `NotesSolrWrite` use for indexing my notes document and saving on server, so in `res` as expected there are two such documents which satisfied query condition and `count.size` gives number of documents which are selected, and i am printing count's values .

so my problem is now i want to delete this documents  from the the server

but i don't know whether i am doing right, after my deleting code still i am getting those documents on server. how to delete that any other way ??

it would be nice if anyone help me

Comment: My guess is you are using this method only [deleteById](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_0_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrClient.html#deleteById%28java.lang.String%29). This returns an `UpdateResponse` response. Please check the status code returned by the solr. I am not sure what is `FTIserver`.

Comment: private SolrServer FTIserver; FTI solr server  and i declare at top of the code sorry not explain that !!

Comment: Did you check the response code?

Comment: solr1.4  this the version of my solr,

Comment: i found the solution, i deleted document by using " FTIserver.deleteByQuery("dontKnow1");"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I deleted document by using

```
FTIserver.deleteByQuery("dontKnow1");"
```